# How can i add smooth triangle bottom of div

Tags: html, css

i have a box and i need to put smooth triangle bottom of the div but i couldn't achieve as i want how can i do this like below image ?

[image]

```css
.slide-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e41113;
  border: 1px solid #df2b2c;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.slide-box a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 10px;
}

.slide-box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid #df2b2c;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-box">
  <a href="#">
          I'm a super <br>box!                     
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that you'll be able to complete what you want with ::after. 
But probably you can use transition rotate and scale on absolute positioned element in the bottom.

Here's the concept:

```css
.slide-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e41113;
  border: 1px solid #df2b2c;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 145px;
  height: 70px;
}

.slide-box a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #e41113;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  z-index:1000;
}

.slide-box .corner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 103px;
  height: 103px;
  background-color: #e41113;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(1, 0.25) rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-box">
  <a href="#">
          I'm a super <br>box!                     
 </a>
  <div class="corner"></div>
</div>
```

Of course the main task will be positioning.

So there you need 2 prerequisitions:

1. With "transform-origin: top left;" you need to keep top of the .corner == height of your main container (don't know why, but bottom:0 not works, maybe youll resolve
   this)
2. The .corner should be square (width=height), and to keep it smooth you need to maintain ratio width(.corner) = width(.slide-box)*sqrt(2). Means width of your corner`s diagonal should be equal to width of main container.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
.slide-box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
 background-color: #df2b2c;
 text-align: left;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-bottom: -75px;
  border-radius: 0 0 25% 25%;
}
.slide-box a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 10px;
}
.corner {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #df2b2c;
 text-align: left;
  margin-left: 95px;
}
.corner:before,
.corner:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background-color: inherit;
}
.corner,
.corner:before,
.corner:after {
 width:  165px;
 height: 165px;
 border-top-right-radius: 30%;
}

.corner {
 transform: rotate(-120deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
}
.corner:before {
 transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414,.707) translate(0,-50%);
}
.corner:after {
 transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707,1.414) translate(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="slide-box">
  <a href="#">
          I'm a super <br>box!                     
 </a>
</div>
<div class="corner"></div>
</div>
```